# I can't use 2 different tools in xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin. I am trying to make a really basic android app but I can't put more than 1 element on the page. I can only put an image, or just a button. How can I use multiple elements?

Before posting this I doubled clicked on the button in the toolbox menu and worked, but I can't move it from the up-left corner and all my elements are overlapping.[That's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEHhU.png)

Comment: Use constraint layout or linear one

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you didn't set any layout to the imageView1 while you set your button toLeftOf imageView1. As [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative#Position) says: By default, all child views are drawn at the top-left of the layout. So, your setting won't take effect since the imageView1 is at top-left and you want your button left to imageView1.

you can simple try the following to make your button to the right of imageView1:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
```

Also, [here's the instructions of RelativeLayout's parameters](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams#summary)